# Openfire 3.9.3 getting There was an error one importing private key and signed certificate

Tags: ssl, openfire

I'm trying to import private key and certificate from the admin console. But i'm getting the following error:

```
There was an error one importing private key and signed certificate
```

Not sure what's the actual issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and follow:

- the [Openfire SSL guide](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/ssl-guide.html)
- the article "[Using Signed SSL Certificates in Openfire](https://vanity-igniterealtime.jiveon.com/docs/DOC-1243)"

The latter points out that if you are importing a certificate from a Certificate installed in Windows, you need to extract the private key by exporting to PFX file.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to follow the instructions provided at Openfire SSL guide as i'm using Ubuntu/Linux.

Comment: @JohnSnow is your certificate a self-sifned one you just created?

Comment: i purchased the ssl certificate from [funio](http://funio.com/ssl), Funio SimpleSSL Certificate

Comment: Followed the instructions at [Openfire SSL guide](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/ssl-guide.html) but no luck.

Comment: It looks like the issue was with the certificate. Now waiting for CA to verify it asap.

Comment: @JohnSnow that would  make sense indeed.